# What profile picture is this, and why do a lot of YouTube's users have it?

Tags: youtube, user-accounts, profile-picture

Here is the profile picture that I am referring to:

[image: Profile picture]

Answer (score 2):

It is a default picture given to new users who have not set up their custom profile picture. It is given by YouTube.